# DropDownListFor not populating correct value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

**My dropdown menu does not populate the correct state when the page loads.** It always starts at the beginning of the list. Right now, I'm just passing the list through using ViewBag which could be the problem.

As you can see in the View code, I have a dropdownlistfor using my Model.StateList but I cant seem to get that to work.

`addy.State`is formatted as The StateAbbr ( ex. "CT", "AL", "AK")

and my dropdown menu (when using the `(SelectList) ViewBag.StateList` method makes a list in this format:

```
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
```

Model

```
public class EditOrderViewModel
    {
        public List<State> StateList { get; set; } 
    }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult EditOrder(int orderId)
{
var model = repositoryScheduling.Order_FindById(orderId);

var stateList = GetStateList();
ViewBag.StateList = new SelectList(stateList, "StateAbbr", "StateNamne");

model.StateList = GetStateList();
return View(model);
}
```

View

```
foreach(var addy in Model.Address)
{
                        <div class="form-group-CityState">
                            <div class="input-group" style="border-right: 0px">
                                <span class="input-group-addon CitySpanAddon" style="text-align: left; border-right: 0px">@Html.LabelFor(model => addy.City)</span>
                               // @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => addy.State, Model.StateList, new {id = "SelectState", @class = "SelectState"})*@
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => addy.State, (SelectList)ViewBag.StateList, new { id = "SelectState", @class = "SelectState" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => addy.State)
                            </div>
                        </div>
}
```

Not sure what this will do but here you go

```
public List<State> GetStateListAll()
        {
            const string query = @"SELECT *
                        FROM
                            states;";


            return this.db.Query<State>(query).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: The first param in the DropDownFor is the object that it keeps the Selected value and posts it back to the server if required, and the same param will be the selected value of the dropdown.
so if you set your addy.State in your controller to be your selected item it should work.

Comment: Show us your GetStateList method.

Comment: OK @MyP3uK , I add the function, but not sure if it will help

Answer (score 0):

You need to set SelectedValue value of your SelectList object that you create.

public ActionResult EditOrder(int orderId)
{
    var model = repositoryScheduling.Order_FindById(orderId);

```
var stateList = GetStateList();
var selectStateList = new SelectList(stateList, "StateAbbr", "StateNamne");
selecteStateList.SelectedValue = model.State // your state id... whatever is in your model.
ViewBag.StateList = selectStateList;
return View(model);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This was my answer. I didn't realize the `SelectList()` had a variable for `selectedValue`

```
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var addy in model.Address)
    {
        var countyList = GetCountyList(addy.State);
        string CountyListCount = "CountyList" + i;
        string StateListCount = "StateList" + i;
        ViewData[CountyListCount] = new SelectList(countyList, null, "CountyName",addy.County);
        ViewData[StateListCount] = new SelectList(stateList, "StateAbbr", "StateName", addy.State);
        i++;
    }
```